# Methylhydrazine Calorimetry

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, calorimetry

Below is a chemistry practice problem.  I am curious why the change in heat of the oxygen molecules doesn't affect the calculations.

> Methylhydrazine ($\ce{CH6N2}$) is commonly used as a liquid rocket fuel. The combustion reaction is below. When 4.00 g of methylhydrazine is combusted in a calorimeter, the temperature increases from $\pu{25.00 ^\circ C}$ to $\pu{39.50 ^\circ C}$.  The calorimeter constant is $\pu{7.794 J/^\circ C}$ and the specific heat of methylhydrazine is $\pu{2.93 J/g ^\circ C}$. What is the overall heat of the reaction (kJ/mol methylhydrazine)?

$$\ce{2 CH6N2(l) +   5 O2(g) -> 2 CO2(g)+   2 N2(g) +   6 H2O(g)}$$

$$\begin{align} \mathrm{molecular\; mass\;\;} \ce{CH6N2} &= \pu{46.08 g/mol}\\
\rightarrow \pu{4 g} \cdot \pu{1 mol}/\pu{46.08g} &= \pu{0.0868 mol} \ce{CH6N2} \\ \rightarrow
 q &= (\pu{4 g})(\pu{39.5 ^\circ C} - \pu{25 ^\circ C})+(\pu{7.794 J/^\circ C})(\pu{39.5 ^\circ C} - \pu{25 ^\circ C}) \\  &= \pu{283 J}  \\ \rightarrow \Delta H &= \pu{-3.26 kJ/mol} \end{align}$$

The change in heat accounts for the $\Delta T$ and temperature change of the calorimeter and the temperature change and $C_p$ and mass of the methyl hydrazine, but why doesn't the oxygen also absorb heat in accordance with its mass and specific heat constant?

-3.26 kJ/mol is the "correct" answer in the answer key, meaning that the absorption of heat by methylhydrazine IS required to get the answer which I didn't expect-I though it would just be the heat absorbed by the calorimeter, but I understand why the methylhydrazine would absorb heat from the reaction, but then why doesn't the oxygen absorb heat since there is actually more mass of oxygen in the calorimeter as mass of methylhydrazine.

Comment: You are saying that the change in heat is the sum of the heat absorbed by the calorimeter and the heat absorbed by the initial compound methyl-hydrazine and that gives the answer that is considered to be correct, but why does the methyl-hydrazine absorb some of the heat according to its Cp and mass, but the oxygen that reacts with the methyl hydrazine doesn't absorb heat.  I'm not sure why.  Is it an error in the problem?

Comment: ^^That's what I'm asking

Comment: There seems to be an error in your equation for q (doesn't affect the question otherwise).

Comment: You need to include the Cp of methylhydrazine in the equation for q.  I don't know why the "correct" answer is arrived at by including the heat change in mehtylhydrazine but not also in the oxygen.  I would think, neither or both.

Comment: I suggest adding the following to the end of your question:
-3.26 kJ/mol is the "correct" answer in the answer key, meaning that the absorption of heat by methylhydrazine IS required to get the answer which I didn't expect-I though it would just be the heat absorbed by the calorimeter, but I understand why the methylhydrazine would absorb heat from the reaction, but then why doesn't the oxygen absorb heat since there is actually more mass of oxygen in the calorimeter as mass of methylhydrazine.

Comment: Simple question.  When calculating the heat of reaction in a calorimeter, does the temperature (or state) change of the reactants and or products affect the calculation?